# regular expression to find until characters?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have these two HTML strings:

```
a="<div> foo: <span>bar</span> </div>"
b="<div> foo: bar <br> </div>"
```

I want to find `foo: bar` from each string.

The way I want to do it is to find from the word 'foo' until I come across a '<' character.

I can do this with the regular expression:

```
foo([^(<)]+)
```

This only finds "foo: bar" from string `b` but not from string `a` because the `<span>` tag is in the way.  So I want to write the regex to look from `foo` until it finds a `<` character ignoring the `<span>` tag.

These are just some of the strings that this has to work on therefore it has to work like states i.e. I can not start removing tags before or after etc.

Basically all I need to know is how to find all characters in a string until I come across a certain character, unless that character is is followed by a set of specified characters, i.e. find until `<` but if `<` is followed by `span>` then look for the next `<`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You should avoid using regex to parse HTML. But if you really want this I could whip up a solution for you.

Comment: Basically, you should just strip down all `<span>` tags ?

Comment: I would first remove the tags with `.gsub(/<.+?>/, '').strip.squeeze(' ')`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the closest I can get to a solution right now would be something like this: http://regex101.com/r/uH2sT1 - which is far from perfect. I would just avoid using regex for this problem really.

Comment: @Lindrian   in this case a regex cant be avoided but i agree with you in general.     Please can you give me a solution in regex ?    For all other help thanks but as stated i can solve this problem by spliting / removing just the span tag

Comment: Obligatory link: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although using regexp to get things out of HTML is usually bad, you could solve the problem in this way:

```
foo, bar = string.gsub(/<.*?>/, '').strip.split
```

Edit: Well, then you might want to look into negative look ahead for regexp: `(?!regpattern)`

```
string[/(foo.*)<((?!span|\/span))/,1]
# match foo followed by all character until < unless the character after that is /span or span
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i cant do this as my actual strings contain more text thank just foo: bar so i must stop on the '<' character but i need to ignore the <span> string in the regex. do you know how to do it this way ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many reasons why you don't want to use regex to process HTML. Your example text is very simple, however it's highly likely in a real-world use the HTML will be a lot more complex and variable, which will cause a regular expression based solution to become very fragile.

Instead, start with the right tool and use a parser:

```
require 'nokogiri'

[
  "<div> foo: <span>bar</span> </div>",
  "<div> foo: bar <br> </div>"
].each do |str|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(str)
  puts doc.at('div').text
end
```

Which outputs:

```
 foo: bar
 foo: bar
```

This uses [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), which is a very capable XML/HTML parser, and is the standard XML/HTML parser for Ruby.